# parsing the affiliateservice api response

Tags: php, api, xml-parsing

I am fetching the TransactionList through [affiliateservice api](http://wiki.affiliatewindow.com/index.php/Affiliate_service_APIV3).
My print_r($response) gives me this (I had to put xx but actually there are numbers there):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [getTransactionListReturn] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [iId] => xx
                    [sStatus] => pending
                    [sType] => normal
                    [sIp] => xx
                    [bPaid] => xx
                    [iPaymentId] => xx
                    [iMerchantId] => xx
                    [fSaleAmount] => xx
                    [fCommissionAmount] => xx
                    [dClickDate] => xx 
                    [dTransactionDate] => xx
                    [sClickref] => xx
                    [aTransactionParts] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [sCommissionGroupName] => STANDARD
                                    [fSaleAmount] => xx
                                    [fCommissionAmount] => xx
                                    [iCommission] => xx
                                    [sCommissionType] => percentage
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [iId] => x
                    [sStatus] => pending
                    [sType] => normal
                    [sIp] => x
                    [bPaid] => 
                    [iPaymentId] => x
                    [iMerchantId] => x
                    [fSaleAmount] => x
                    [fCommissionAmount] => x
                    [dClickDate] => x
                    [dTransactionDate] => x
                    [sClickref] => x
                    [sSearchSiteName] => x
                    [sSearchSiteKeyword] => x
                    [aTransactionParts] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [sCommissionGroupName] => DEFAULT
                                    [fSaleAmount] => x
                                    [fCommissionAmount] => x
                                    [iCommission] => x
                                    [sCommissionType] => percentage
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [getTransactionListCountReturn] => stdClass Object
        (
            [iRowsReturned] => 2
            [iRowsAvailable] => 386
        )

)
```

So, my question is how can I "parse" this in PHP? I mean how can I access these data? I mean something like

```
$response[0]->sStatus;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is an instance of the `stdClass`, the standard class in PHP (except for the arrays, of course :)).

This means you would use `->` to access the properties of each object.

```
$someSaleAmount = 
       $response->getTransactionListReturn[0]->aTransactionParts[0]->fSaleAmount;
```

You probably got this from using `json_decode()`. You can set the second parameter to `true` if you'd rather deal with arrays than objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing is object, than it's array, than it's object again with some values.
I would go for something like this:

```
<code>
$response = $obj->getTransactionListReturn();
foreach($response as $key => $value) {
  // key is index (0, 1, ..., n)
  // value is the variable like iId
  echo $value->id;
}
</code>
```

Should work.